# unable to from Convert Pascal VOC to tfrecords for tensor flow object detection API

Tags: computer-vision, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api, tfrecord

unable to from Convert Pascal VOC to tfrecords for tensor flow object detection API , reference : https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#create-tensorflow-records

```
!python /workspace/scripts/generate_tfrecord1.py -x /workspace/kitti_dataset/training -l /workspace/annotations/label_map.pbtxt -o /workspace/annotations/train.record
!python /workspace/scripts/generate_tfrecord1.py -x /workspace/kitti_dataset/validation -l /workspace/annotations/label_map.pbtxt -o /workspace/annotations/train.record
```

error that I am getting :

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/__init__.py:98: UserWarning: unable to load libtensorflow_io_plugins.so: unable to open file: libtensorflow_io_plugins.so, from paths: ['/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/libtensorflow_io_plugins.so']
caused by: ['/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/libtensorflow_io_plugins.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3tsl5mutexC1Ev']
  warnings.warn(f"unable to load libtensorflow_io_plugins.so: {e}")
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/__init__.py:104: UserWarning: file system plugins are not loaded: unable to open file: libtensorflow_io.so, from paths: ['/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/libtensorflow_io.so']
caused by: ['/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/libtensorflow_io.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK10tensorflow4data11DatasetBase8FinalizeEPNS_15OpKernelContextESt8functionIFN3tsl8StatusOrISt10unique_ptrIS1_NS5_4core15RefCountDeleterEEEEvEE']
  warnings.warn(f"file system plugins are not loaded: {e}")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/scripts/generate_tfrecord1.py", line 172, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 36, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 312, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 258, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/workspace/scripts/generate_tfrecord1.py", line 159, in main
    examples = xml_to_csv(args.xml_dir)
  File "/workspace/scripts/generate_tfrecord1.py", line 92, in xml_to_csv
    int(bndbox.find('xmin').text),
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n    692.09\n   '
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/__init__.py:98: UserWarning: unable to load libtensorflow_io_plugins.so: unable to open file: libtensorflow_io_plugins.so, from paths: ['/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/libtensorflow_io_plugins.so']
caused by: ['/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/libtensorflow_io_plugins.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3tsl5mutexC1Ev']
  warnings.warn(f"unable to load libtensorflow_io_plugins.so: {e}")
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/__init__.py:104: UserWarning: file system plugins are not loaded: unable to open file: libtensorflow_io.so, from paths: ['/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/libtensorflow_io.so']
caused by: ['/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/libtensorflow_io.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK10tensorflow4data11DatasetBase8FinalizeEPNS_15OpKernelContextESt8functionIFN3tsl8StatusOrISt10unique_ptrIS1_NS5_4core15RefCountDeleterEEEEvEE']
  warnings.warn(f"file system plugins are not loaded: {e}")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/scripts/generate_tfrecord1.py", line 172, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 36, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 312, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 258, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/workspace/scripts/generate_tfrecord1.py", line 159, in main
    examples = xml_to_csv(args.xml_dir)
  File "/workspace/scripts/generate_tfrecord1.py", line 92, in xml_to_csv
    int(bndbox.find('xmin').text),
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '583.43'
```

unable to from Convert Pascal VOC to tfrecords for tensor flow object detection API training

Answer (score 0):

The cause is that you have renamed the image after labeling, causing the image name (.jpg) and label file name (.XML) to not match, resulting in the name in the image and CSV file not matching.
The solution is to create the script to rename the XML file.
and then exported to CSV again

Comment: I am a bit confused , I did not rename anything. The labels and corresponding images have same names. except the extention. jpg for image and xml for labels.